# Revert a jQuery draggable object back to its original container on out event of droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable item which if not dropped in a droppable will revert. This works well until a user drops an item in the droppable. If they decide they've made a mistake anytime they pull the draggable out it reverts to the droppable. I would prefer that on out and deactivate the draggable goes back to its original container.

My code is below but I have provided [a sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTD8y/1/).

HTML

```
<div id="origin">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>I revert when I'm not dropped</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop me here</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ 
        revert:  function(dropped) {
           var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
           if(!dropped) alert("I'm reverting!");
           return !dropped;
        } 
    }).each(function() {
        var top = $(this).position().top;
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        $(this).data('orgTop', top);
        $(this).data('orgLeft', left);
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
                // doesn't work but something like this
                ui.draggable.mouseup(function () {
                var top = ui.draggable.data('orgTop');
                var left = ui.draggable.data('orgLeft');
                ui.position = { top: top, left: left };
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `Unfortunately, for my purposes out fires too soon (the moment the draggable leaves.)` Isn't that rather the purpose of `out`? Do you just want to find out if they `mouseup` while `out`?

Comment: @drachenstern good idea. I'll experiment w/ that in the out event, but either way doesn't solve the issue of the draggable reverting back to the droppable.

Comment: Glad I could help, still not sure what I triggered in your head. I think tho, that the draggable loses it's "home" droppable once you move it. You may need to store that information in an ancillary method somewhere.

Comment: @drachenstern I was going for that w/ storing the original position. I just can't get it to use that instead of the it's new position in the droppable. :( btw: code is updated to reflect your great suggestion.

Comment: You need two droppable regions. When you're not over either one, and you return `!dropped`, that's when you need to handle where to drop to. Don't do it on out or on mouseup. It doesn't have anywhere to put the reverted once you've dropped on the droppable zone. (alternately just remove the "position:relative" when you don't detect that you're over the droppable zone)

Comment: @drachenstern That makes good sense, how do I assign which region to send it to?

Comment: Can't get it to work with 2.1.1. get two errors Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Index:136
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'originalPosition' of undefined

Answer (score 140, accepted):

> - **TESTED** with **jquery 1.11.3** & **jquery-ui 1.11.4**
> - **DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of-d/

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
        }
    });
    $("#droppable").droppable();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this solution. It works great. Was wondering if anybody could explain the finer details of it?

Comment: @leetou: i have update the code and added hack explanation on demo site. ;)

Comment: Thank you for updating this for jQuery 1.9! :)

Comment: Ditto, thanks for the updated version, and the helpful explanation of the code.

Comment: The demo link is broken

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'originalPosition' of undefined

Comment: Quinn Wilson: demo restored and tested with new jquery and jquery ui versions

Comment: @andre de waard: most probably depends on what version of jquery you are using see the commented section to check it out...

Comment: Nice, but I had to change `$(this).data("uiDraggable")` to `$(this).data("ui-draggable")` and then it magically worked.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this will work for your actual use, but it works in your test case - updated at http://jsfiddle.net/sTD8y/27/ .

I just made it so that the built-in revert is only used if the item has not been dropped before.  If it has been dropped, the revert is done manually.  You could adjust this to animate to some calculated offset by checking the actual CSS properties, but I'll let you play with that because a lot of it depends on the CSS of the draggable and it's surrounding DOM structure.

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        revert:  function(dropped) {
             var $draggable = $(this),
                 hasBeenDroppedBefore = $draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
                 wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
             if(wasJustDropped) {
                 // don't revert, it's in the droppable
                 return false;
             } else {
                 if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
                     // don't rely on the built in revert, do it yourself
                     $draggable.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 }, 'slow');
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     // just let the built in revert work, although really, you could animate to 0,0 here as well
                     return true;
                 }
             }
        }
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
            $(ui.draggable).data('hasBeenDropped', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to revert the element to the source position if it's not dropped inside a `#droppable` element, just save the original parent element of the draggable at the start of the script (instead of the position), and if you verify that it's not dropped into `#droppable`, then just restore the parent of `#draggable` to this original element.

So, replace this:

```
}).each(function() {
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    $(this).data('orgTop', top);
    $(this).data('orgLeft', left);
});
```

with this:

```
}).each(function() {
    $(this).data('originalParent', $(this).parent())
});
```

Here, you'll have the original parent element of the draggable. Now, you have to restore it's parent in a precise moment.

`drop` is called every time the element is dragged out from the droppable, not at the stop. So, you're adding a lot of event callbacks. This is wrong, because you never clean the `mouseup` event. A good place where you can hook a callback and check if the element was dropped inside or outside the `#droppable` element, is `revert`, and you're doing it right now, so, just delete the `drop` callback.

When the element is dropped, and needs to know if it should be reverted or not, you know for sure that you'll not have any other interaction from the user until the new drag start. So, using the same condition you're using to know if it should revert or know, let's replace this `alert` with a fragment of code that: restores the parent element to the original div, and resets the `originalPosition` from the `draggable` internals. The `originalPosition` proeprty is setted at the time of `_mouseStart`, so, if you change the owner of the element, you should reset it, in order to make the animation of revert go to the proper place. So, let's set this to `{top: 0, left: 0}`, making the animation go to the origin point of the element:

```
revert: function(dropped) {
    var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
    if(!dropped) {
        $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {top:0, left:0}
        $(this).appendTo($(this).data('originalParent'))
    }
    return !dropped;
}
```

And that's it! You can check this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/eUs3e/1/

Take into consideration that, if in any jQuery's UI update, the behavior of `revert` or `originalPosition` changes, you'll need to update your code in order to make it work. Keep in mind that.

If you need a solution which doesn't make use of calls to the internals of ui.draggable, you can make your `body` an droppable element with `greedy` option defined as `false`. You'll have to make sure that your `body` elements take the full screen.

Good luck!

Comment: Gonzalo, I don't think the 'originalParent' logic is necessary here.  When you drop a draggable, the underlying DOM structure doesn't actually change.

Comment: Yep! You're right. It's not necessary :-) I'm used to work with ULs and LIs for draggables/droppables. Thanks!

Comment: what you have here definitely works, but the readd is a bit jerky in that if used with an unordered list. By appending it jumps to the bottom. That said this is the more readable solution. From what I can tell `drop` is only called when the element is actually dropped. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ahsteele perhaps you can provide the actual DOM you're trying to work with.  It might help us to give you a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone's interested, here's my solution to the problem. It works completely independently of the Draggable objects, by using events on the Droppable object instead. It works quite well:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        opacity: .4,
        create: function(){$(this).data('position',$(this).position())},
        cursor:'move',
        start:function(){$(this).stop(true,true)}
    });

    $('.active').droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).unbind("mouseup");
        },
        drop:function(event, ui){
            snapToMiddle(ui.draggable,$(this));
        },
        out:function(event, ui){
            $(ui.helper).mouseup(function() {
                snapToStart(ui.draggable,$(this)); 
            });
        }
    });
}); 

function snapToMiddle(dragger, target){
    var topMove = target.position().top - dragger.data('position').top + (target.outerHeight(true) - dragger.outerHeight(true)) / 2;
    var leftMove= target.position().left - dragger.data('position').left + (target.outerWidth(true) - dragger.outerWidth(true)) / 2;
    dragger.animate({top:topMove,left:leftMove},{duration:600,easing:'easeOutBack'});
}
function snapToStart(dragger, target){
    dragger.animate({top:0,left:0},{duration:600,easing:'easeOutBack'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's related about revert origin : to set origin when the object is drag : just use `$(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {top:0, left:0};`

For example : i use like this

```js
drag: function() {
        var t = $(this);
        left = parseInt(t.css("left")) * -1;
        if(left > 0 ){
            left = 0;
            t.draggable( "option", "revert", true );
            $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {top:0, left:0};
        } 
        else t.draggable( "option", "revert", false );

        $(".slider-work").css("left",  left);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another easy way to deal with this problem, you just need the attribute  " connectToSortable:" to draggable like as below code:

```
$("#a1,#a2").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#b,#a",
        revert: 'invalid',
    });
```

PS: More detail and example
[How to move Draggable objects between source area and target area with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682909/how-to-move-draggable-objects-between-source-area-and-target-area-with-jquery/51683501#51683501)