# Javascript - return dragged image back to its original location

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am using the following code to drag images into an area of the screen. I want to know, is there a code that I can use to send the image back to its original location, or at least back to its original div. I need to do this, because after a certain time (lets just say 100s) I need a particular image to go back. So lets say I drag both images into the area, after 100s I want the first image back to its original location

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
   <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
   <img id="drag2" src="img_logo2.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use jqueryui drag and drop. In that you can use revert function I think thats you want..

Comment: See this link http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Comment: I need to use the current method

Comment: On start draggin in `drage(ev)` save 'ev.pageX` and `ev.pageY`. On drop you can use those values to adjust elements position.

Comment: @Matt9Atkins this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735270/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of) can deal with your problem