# Jquery UI - Allow droppable to have blockable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am unsure how to achieve what I am trying to do.  I set up an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable'
});
```

The green box is a valid droppable.  The red box is not.  If the draggable is dropped on the red, even the red that is over top of the green, I want it to be invalid and revert.  In the example this is not working.

Is this achievable? 
I have combed over the API and through other questions and have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add both elements to the droppable types, and then check the element it had been dropped on. If it is `block` then revert.

http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/12/

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('#droppable, #block').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if (this.id == 'block') {
            ui.draggable.draggable({ revert: true  });
        } else {
            ui.draggable.draggable({ revert: "invalid"});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Though this is accepted answer @user2437462 there is a problem with this solution. once you Drop it on Green BOX then it is also Droppable on White Area... As ypu are making `revert: false` ..See my naswer it has solved that problem

Comment: @rahulmaindargi Thanks, I missed that. Code is much simpler than you posted, set `revert: "invalid"` rather than `false` (to match the original declaration). Code above updated

Comment: If you need to allow drag out of green box then http://stackoverflow.com/a/5848800/661447 or set up another droppable to allow accept back.

Comment: @jammykam if revert is simple as 'revert: "invalid"' then its ok but what if its `anonymus function` or something else.. ? my answer will take care of that too.. as i am storing the original value once ... and using it..

Comment: Sure and good point, but it depends on the OP's requirements. Why over-engineer things? You could just as easily declare `var revertDraggable = function(){}` and set that to `revert` http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/13/ Just my personal preference since it reads easier IMO

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue and thanks for fixing it.  As of right I am just using "invalid" so this solution works for me, but this discussion will be helpful if that changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/4/show

http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/4/

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.hide();
        console.log(ui);
        var target = document.elementFromPoint(ui.offset.left, ui.offset.top);
        if (!target || target.id != "droppable") ui.draggable.draggable({
            revert: true
        });
        else  ui.draggable.draggable({
            revert: false
        });
        ui.draggable.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: After test, this is buggy but could bring you in the right way, i hope

Comment: Thanks, this was on the right track. jammykam's answer is a bit cleaner and easier though.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution is cleaner but has 1 problem. Once draggable is Dropped over Green Area, it will beocome Droppable even on white Area... (Note `revert: false`)
Updates to  that answer with correct code.

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/11/)**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('#droppable, #block').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if(!ui.draggable.data('original')){
            ui.draggable.data('original',ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert"));
        }
        if (this.id == 'block') {
            ui.draggable.draggable({ revert: true  });
        } else {
            ui.draggable.draggable({ revert: ui.draggable.data('original')  });
        }
    }
});
```

---

Looks like this question already has answer. but here is my attempt to solve same problem.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zs6US/10/)**

```
$('#block').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.data('revert')) {
            ui.draggable.data('revert', false);
            var old = ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert");
            ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", true);
            setTimeout(function () {
               ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", old);
            }, 100);
        }
    },
    out: function (event) {
        $('.draggable').data('revert', false);
    },
    over: function (event,ui) {
       ui.draggable.data('revert', true);
    }
});

$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: function (elem) {
      if ($('.draggable').data('revert')) {
            return false;
        }
        return elem.hasClass("draggable");
    }
});

$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```