# jQuery - How do I make sure draggable can only be dragged to 2 places?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I got a little problem, which will be easy to solve for some smart people around here. I have been breaking my head about it for days now.

I used jQuery succesfully to create draggables and droppables. The only problem I can't solve is the following:

**How do I make sure that a draggable only can be dragged to a droppable? If it is not dragged inside a droppable it should return to it's starting location.**

I use the following code (which works succesfully) to make sure a draggable can only be dragged to a droppable, or else it will jump back to it's starting location.

```
var question = '#question' + i;
    $(question).draggable( {
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        snap: '#content',
        revert: 'invalid',
);
```

The `revert: invalid` part does the trick.

However, how do I do this for when it already once has been dragged into a droppable? When I drag a draggable into the droppable, and then drag it outside again it can stay anywhere on the screen (this is because I set the option to false: `ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );` I need the draggable to return to it's starting location again when it is dragged out of the droppable.

Can anyone push me in the right direction? / Any suggestions?

JSFiddle : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJB6Z/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a revert function like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735270/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of) : (With a jsfiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCTkR/))

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
        }
    });
    $("#droppable").droppable();
});
```

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.7.2 and jQuery UI version 1.10.3. When I replace `uiDraggable` with `draggable` or `ui-draggable` (because `uiDraggable`doesn't work) it doesn't work either. Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/6zGLk/)**

js code:

```
$( init );

function init() {
    // Create droppable
            $('<div id="slot1"></div>').appendTo( '#questionSlots' ).droppable( {
              accept: '#questionsHolder div',
              hoverClass: 'hovered',
                drop:function(event, ui){
                    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
                }
            } );

    $('#questionsHolder').droppable( {
              //accept: '#slot1 div',
              hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
                 drop:function(event, ui){
                    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
                }            
            } );

// Make question draggable
    $("#question1").draggable( {
        cursor: 'move',
        //snap: '#content',
        revert: 'invalid'
        } );


}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem !

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when you remove the draggable from the droppable again it doesn't go back to it's original location.

Comment: But try dropping it on the `question holder` div, the question will again drop into it !

Comment: That works, but the problem I'm having is the following: If a question has been dropped onto the droppable, and I remove it again, it should revert back to it's starting location ('the question holder div')