# How to return the draggable element into the options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to return the element `.draggable-box` into the `containment` option, how can i achieve this?

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

$(".draggable-box").draggable({
    containment: [($(this).width() / 2), 50, windowWidth - 100, windowHeight - 200]
});
```

If I use `$(this)`, `window` is returned...

Comment: Dont know if this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735270/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use `$(this)`, `window` is returned...

You need a reference to each `.draggable` element:

```
$(".draggable-box").each(function ( i, draggable ) {
  var $draggable = $(draggable);
  $draggable.draggable({
    containment: [($draggable.width() / 2), 50, windowWidth - 100, windowHeight - 200]
  });
});
```

Note that inside the `each` callback `this` will refer to the element (`draggable` in my example) so you could use `this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `draggable-box` element in it's own variable. Try this:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var $draggableBox = $(".draggable-box");

$draggableBox.draggable({
    containment: [($draggableBox.width() / 2), 50, windowWidth - 100, windowHeight - 200]
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `.draggable-box` could refer to any number of elements.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it... I took the code and I try and did not work with various elements...